# How to connect Angular Material Datepicker to AgGrid's Cell Editor for date-type fields?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an Angular9 application that uses AgGrid tables. There are several tables that contains date columns -- 'pickup_date', 'return_date', etc. I want to make user use a datepicker to select dates when editing cells in those columns. AgGrid's documentation have an example of using jQuery's datepicker for that purpose -- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#example-datepicker-cell-editing . But I want to avoid using jQuery in my app. Is there any way to connect any other datepicker, let's say Angular Material Datepicker, to Cell Editor?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use a `cellRenderer` (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/)) to implement this. You can then place your Angular Material date picker inside the cell to display when being edited.

I've created a StackBlitz example for your [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-7nyzno).

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! It seems like it's what I need!  I tried to implement this approach to my app and it shows material datepicker widget as it should. Although I have a couple of issues: 1) ERROR TypeError: input is undefined
    focusOnInputNextTick mat-date-picker-component.ts:65; 2) I need to reformat date to dd-mm-yyyy. I think I need to use Moment adapter to change format, right?